# How to save username and password using Remember me in drupal login form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to save username and password using Remember me checkbox. If I clicked Remember me checkbox the username and password should be save for future. In drupal I am using Remember me module to do this but I am not able to save the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Remember me is not saving username and password anywhere. It's just prolonging php session, so you stay logged in longer.

If you want your browser to remember password it's up to browser. Maybe there are some settings for that. Also, password must be defined in html as type "password" so browser can figure it out and attribute "autocomplete" of password input field should not be set to "off"